# manipulating html with br selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an application using backbone. In one of the views, there is a whiteboard element which is rendered as markdown. When this is being rendered as a inline row in another view with columns, the layout has trouble when there are 
 tags in the markdown object.

How do I get rid of `<br>` and the following text but keep the initial part?

Code:

```
var wh_html = $('<div/>').html(marked(this.model.get('whiteboard'),
              {sanitize: true, breaks:false, smartypants: false}));
var fline = wh_html.find('p:first,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6').first().html();
```

When I put text like:
    [google](http://www.google.com)  Its great !

The "Its great !" comes on the next line and this breaks the layout.

I want to be able to work on the wh_html so that I get:
    [google](http://www.google.com)

Please help.

Comment: You dont have any <br> in the code but it acts like it has?

Answer (score 1):

If you have in some part of that codethe html in text,

you can get rid of the < br /> element by simply having e.g.

```
str=str.replace(/<br>/gi, "\n");
```

or substituting it with any other text instead of textual newline "\n".

**edit:**

You wanted to strip away everything from the tag till end. Googled and found sth useful for you:

```
var s = 'google.fi <br/> It s great';
var n = s.indexOf('<br/>');
s = s.substring(0, n != -1 ? n : s.length);
```